# How to convert the JSON file as a response to my own server

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, excel

I have this code to convert Excel file to JSON format and it gave a JSON file, may I know how to convert this as a response?
I tried using res.send the js code as usual but it gave the directory/inner codes instead. Please help

```
    let express = require('express');
    let server = express();
    let upload = require('express-fileupload');
    let importExcel = require('convert-excel-to-json');
    
    server.use(upload());
    
    server.get('/', (req, res)=> {
        res.sendFile(__dirname+'/index.html');
    });
    
    server.post('/', (req, res)=>{
        let file = req.files.filename;
        let filename = file.name;
        file.mv('./excel/'+filename,(err)=>{
            if (err){
                res.send('fail');
            }else{
                let result = importExcel({
                    sourceFile : './excel/'+filename
                });
            }
        });
    }); 
    
    
    server.listen(9000,()=> {console.log('Server listen to port 9000')});
```

This is another js file to convert excel --> JSON

```
const xlsx = require('xlsx'); var fs = require('fs'); const { json } = require('express');

function convertExcelFileToJsonUsingXlsx() {
    const file = xlsx.readFile('./excel/Book1.xlsx');

    const sheetNames = file.SheetNames;
    
    let parsedData = [];

    const testData = xlsx.utils.sheet_to_json(file.Sheets[sheetNames]);
    parsedData.push(...testData);

    generateJSONFile(parsedData); }

function generateJSONFile(data) {
    try {
        fs.writeFileSync('data.json', JSON.stringify(data))
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err)
    } }
```

but instead of giving out as a JSON file, I want to convert the JSON as a response to my server using

```
server.get('/json', (req, res) {
        res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/html; charset=utf-8');
        res.send('');});
```

Comment: Your details are unclear. What exactly do you want to return?

Comment: I've added an answer, but this question is very unclear. Please specify what you want to accomplish, and what you've tried (with results). Send your code in ``` blocks, not images.

Comment: I have made some changes, sorry its my first time using stack. Hope the changes are a bit clear of what I wanted, Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you're using express, as you mentioned `res`.

```
const json = require('path_to_json.json')

app.get('...', (req, res) => {
    // ...

    res.send(JSON.stringify(json));
});
```